# Collect position of characters in list of strings

Tags: python, list, sorting, count

If I have a list of strings and I want to gather the position of each character in the string, what would be the best way? For example, if I had a list:

```
text = []
stopword = ""
while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if line.strip() == stopword:
        break
    text.append(line)

text = ['fda', 'adf', 'esf', 'esfe']
```

and I wanted to create something like:

```
 newlst = ['faee', 'ddss', 'afff', 'e']
```

Is there a simple way? I'm creating multitudes of `for` loops and it seems convoluted.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`izip_longest` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)*:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> text = ['fda', 'adf', 'esf', 'esfe']
>>> map(''.join, izip_longest(*text, fillvalue=''))
['faee', 'ddss', 'afff', 'e']
```

This creates an iterator of tuples of the characters at each position:

```
>>> list(izip_longest(*text, fillvalue=''))
[('f', 'a', 'e', 'e'), ('d', 'd', 's', 's'), ('a', 'f', 'f', 'f'), ('', '', '', 'e')]
```

Then uses [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to convert the tuples back into strings. If the `*` syntax is unfamiliar, see [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761)

---

* *If using Python 3.x, note that this function has been renamed to `zip_longest`, as `zip` now takes the iterator behaviour and `izip` no longer exists - see e.g. [What's New in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists).*